# Attaching a stylesheet with dirname(__FILE__) won't work even though the file is there

Tags: php, relative-path

I have a PHP class that creates a header for my html file.. It's included, and that file is included again.. So I thought that the `dirname(__FILE__)` function could work.. But it says it can't find the stylesheet..

I'm using mamp on os x, and when I take the path that I get from `dirname(__FILE__)./../stylesheets/stylesheet.css` into the terminal, the file is found.. I'm pretty sure the path is correct.

What can be the reason for this? I use `dirname(__FILE__)` all the time when I include files, that works..

Thanks

```
EDIT:

Files and directories:
/data/main.php
/stylesheets/stylesheet.css
/public/index.php

In the main.php:


public function createHeader(){
    `$stylesheetpath = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../stylesheets/stylesheet.css";`
    `$header = "\n";`
    return $header
}
```

Comment: can you please paste some code so we can help you... Usually that should work

Answer (score 8):

The relative path should be ok.

```
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="../stylesheets/stylesheet.css" TYPE="text/css">
```

An absolute path here would be absolute with respect to the document root, not the file system.

`dirname(__FILE__)` is appropriate for including script files server-side, but not for paths used by the client.  Simply put, the link tag is an instruction to the browser to go ahead and request that file.

Comment: "dirname(__FILE__) is appropriate for including script files server-side, but not for paths used by the client." thanks did'nt know that! :)

Answer (score 1):

edit: read the question incorrectly...

use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
```

for css

Answer (score 1):

From you file structure, `/stylesheets/` is out of the public reach, it must be placed inside the `/public/` folder for the browsers to retrieve the files:

```
/data/main.php
/public/stylesheets/stylesheet.css
/public/index.php
```

Even when the file `main.php` is working, the file being viewed by the browser is `index.php`, so the relative path would be `stylesheets/stylesheet.css`

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem with [partial case-sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699412/case-inconsistency-of-php-file-paths-on-mac-mamp) on Mac OSX?